# How To Generate An Image/SVG File Using A CSS Gradient

Tags: css

I have the following CSS gradient and I want to generate an Image or a SVG file from this but I have no idea how to do this. Your advice very much appreciated.

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(211, 208, 211) 0%, rgb(235, 236, 234) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(211, 208, 211) 0%, rgb(235, 236, 234) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(211, 208, 211) 0%, rgb(235, 236, 234) 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(211, 208, 211) 0%, rgb(235, 236, 234) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(211, 208, 211) 0%, rgb(235, 236, 234) 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take your color codes to photoshop and generate it.
or take a screenshot and crop it in photoshop.